# Sort a multi dimendional PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, soap

I am using an XML API service & SOAP to get some data. I am using the below code to sokut the hotelCode (multi dimensional valiable ).

```
 <?php
$hotelCodes = array() ;
$availHotels = $checkAvailability->availableHotels ;
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    $hotelCodes[] = $hotel->hotelCode ;
}
?>
```

And below i echoing them

```
    <li>
    <?php echo $hotelCodes[0];?></li>
    <li>
    <?php echo $hotelCodes[1];?></li>
    <li>
    <?php echo $hotelCodes[2];?>
    </li>
    <li>
    <?php echo $hotelCodes[3];?>
    </li>
```

The think that SOAP responds with all the availeble hotelcodes that are availeble for that certain search that i made.
 i receive the response as below example:

```
 - ABCDE - This is Hotel Code 0 and it the code of Hotel Y / Double standard Room / Room Only
 - ABCDE - This is Hotel Code 0 and it the code of Hotel Y / Double standard Room / Breakfast
 - ZXCVB - This is Hotel Code 0 and it the code of Hotel X / Double standard Room / Room Only
 - ABCDE - This is Hotel Code 0 and it the code of Hotel Y / Twin Toom / Room Only
```

The `print_r($hotelCodes);` is

```
Array ( [0] => ABCDE [1] => ABCDE[2] => ZXCVB [3] => ABCDE)
```

How can i sort the `$hotelCodes[]` so i can get unique values ( unique hotel codes )

I am trying now:

```
<?php
$hotelCodes = array() ;
$availHotels = $checkAvailability->availableHotels ;
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    $hotelCodes[] = $hotel->hotelCode ;
    $result = array_unique($hotelCodes);
print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Print_r is :

```
Array ( [0] => ITOI6P ) Array ( [0] => ITOI6P [1] => ITR03M ) Array ( [0] => ITOI6P [1] => ITR03M ) Array ( [0] => ITOI6P [1] => ITR03M [3] => ITJ64C ) Array ( [0] => ITOI6P [1] => ITR03M [3] => ITJ64C ) Array ( [0] => ITOI6P [1] => ITR03M [3] => ITJ64C [5] => ITRC24 )
```

And the echo are :

```
<li><?php echo $result[0];?></li> - displays : ITOI6P
<li><?php echo $result[1];?></li> - displays : ITR03M
<li><?php echo $result[2];?></li> - displays : empty
<li><?php echo $result[3];?></li> - displays : ITJ64C
<li><?php echo $result[4];?></li> - displays : empty
<li><?php echo $result[5];?></li> - displays : ITRC24
```

How can i get all of them filled with the next in order unique hotel codes ?

Comment: Are you only trying to get the codes or do you need the data for each hotel having that code as well?

Comment: I need only the codes in this step. The data that each hotel have i can pull it based on the hotel code in a sepparate page ( details page ).

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the unique codes then just call `array_unique` on the array of codes. If you need information for all the hotels with a given code then you can create that as part of your loop insted:

```
$hotelCodes = array() ;
$availHotels = $checkAvailability->availableHotels ;
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    if (!isset($hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode])) {
        $hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode] = array();
    }
    // you could ofcourse just take specific info from $hotel and put it in here.
    $hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode][] = $hotel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique function which will remove the duplicates. Before applying that you might want to do an array_flip so that your hotel codes are now your values and then vice-versa.